# here api how to disable turn-to-turn navigation arrow

Tags: android, here-api

I'm using here android sdk and using turn-to-turn navigation. I want to disable these navigation arrows, but can't find anything at api for that. 
[image]

With custom color scheme I was able to turn off almost all arrow elements by setting:

```
GuidanceArrow.Color
GuidanceArrow.OutlineColor
GuidanceArrow.ShadowColor
```

to `Color.TRANSPARENT` but somehow the arrow shadow don't disappear:
[image]

Comment: try to change ZIndex to 0 or -1

Comment: ZIndex of what?

Comment: ZIndex of the arrow

Comment: Don't know how to obtain reference for that via api =(

Comment: I changed the zIndex, it doesn't help @OussemaAroua

Answer (score 0):

Only way with the current APIs is to not set a map to navigation manager during guidance. However, this means you have to move the map yourself whenever navigation manager calls back with events.